# json object raw data field into php array

Tags: php, json, splunk

I have a JSON object data extract from splunk, one of the fields `_raw` contains a string of data but since it's value is not a valid json string I can't seem to convert it to a php array using **json_decode()**

Any ideas how I might be able to convert the value of `_raw` into a php array?

This is my json data

```
{
    "result": {
        "_raw": "Jun 30 06:51:04 blablabla.com apache2: event_id="something" event="something" app="testapp" serial_number="066f1cda" revoke_reason="key compromise" revoke_comment="xxxxxx" delay_revoke="15" url="/blablabla.php" account_id="123456" user_id="xxxxxxx" staff_id="xxxx" staff_name="todd" ip_address="123.123.123.123"",
        "splunk_server": "splunkin02.localhost.com"
    },
    "results_link": "https://splunk.sffew.com",
    "app": "search",
    "search_name": "TEST",
    "owner": "toodles@sfsfe.com",
    "sid": "scheduler_blahlahlah"
}
```

Want to be able to reference each value within the string, like so

```
Array (
     [event_id] => something
     [event] => something
     [app] => testapp
     [serial_number] => 066f1cda
     [revoke_reason] => key compromise
     [revoke_comment] => xxxxxx
     [delay_revoke] => 15
     [url] => /blablabla.php
     [account_id] => 123456
     [user_id] => xxxxxxx
     [staff_id] => xxxx
     [staff_name] => todd
     [ip_address] => 123.123.123.123
)
```

Comment: if it helps the key & value i need always start after the word `apache2`

Comment: Could you please clarify if your JSON is actually valid or not? What you have above isn't valid due to the quotes in `_raw` not being escaped but I think it would be highly unlikely for a mature tool like Splunk to produce invalid JSON

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it `preg_match_all()` and `foreach()`,

```
<?php
$re = '/"_raw": (.*)(?=,)/m';
$str = '{
    "result": {
        "_raw": "Jun 30 06:51:04 blablabla.com apache2: event_id="something" event="something" app="testapp" serial_number="066f1cda" revoke_reason="key compromise" revoke_comment="xxxxxx" delay_revoke="15" url="/blablabla.php" account_id="123456" user_id="xxxxxxx" staff_id="xxxx" staff_name="todd" ip_address="123.123.123.123"",
        "splunk_server": "splunkin02.localhost.com"
    },
    "results_link": "https://splunk.sffew.com",
    "app": "search",
    "search_name": "TEST",
    "owner": "toodles@sfsfe.com",
    "sid": "scheduler_blahlahlah"
}';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER, 0);
$parsable_array = explode(' ',$matches[0][1]);
$expected_array = array_filter($parsable_array, function ($var) { return (stripos($var, '=') != false); });
$final_result = [];
foreach($expected_array as $str){
    list($key,$value) = explode('=',$str);
    $final_result[$key] = trim($value,'"');
}
print_r($final_result);
?>
```

**WORKING DEMO:** https://3v4l.org/fFQSZ

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_match_all()` to find all your `key="value"` pairs after `apache2:` like this..

```php
$raw = $json_decode($json)->result->_raw;

$marker = 'apache2: ';
$startAt = strpos($raw, $marker) + strlen($marker);

preg_match_all('/(\w+)="(.*?)"/', $raw, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, $startAt);

$result = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Demo ~ https://3v4l.org/idlRs

Comment: Have you not manually frigged the input here to make the JSONString legal, which the OP's input is not

Comment: @RiggsFolly I assumed OP's JSON was actually valid since it's coming from Splunk. I doubt very much it would not be escaping the quotes within the `_raw` value